# Scikit-learn KDTree query_radius return both count and ind?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, kdtree

I'm trying to return both `count` (the number of neighbors) and `ind` (indices of said neighbors) but I can't unless I call `query_radius` twice, which although computationally intensive, is actually **faster** for me in Python than iterating through and counting the sizes of each row in `ind`! This seems terribly inefficient so I wonder is there a way to just return them both in one call?

I tried to access the count and ind objects of `tree` after calling `query_radius` but it doesn't exist. There's no efficient way to do this in numpy, is there?

```
>>> array = np.array([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [6,2,3]])
>>> tree = KDTree(array)
>>> neighbors = tree.query_radius(array, 1)
>>> tree.ind
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.KDTree' object has no attribute 'ind'
>>> tree.count
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.KDTree' object has no attribute 'count'
```

Comment: Hi, was your issue solved? If so, please upvote and accept. Else, provide the feedback to improve the ans. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this dataset:

```
array = np.random.random((10**5, 3))*10
tree = KDTree(array)
```

There are 3 options as you identify in your question:

1) Call `tree.query_radius` twice to get the neighbors and their counts.

```
neighbors = tree.query_radius(array, 1)
counts = tree.query_radius(array, 1, count_only=1)
```

This takes 8.347s.

2) Get only the neighbors and then get the counts by iterating through them:

```
neighbors = tree.query_radius(array, 1)
counts = []
for i in range(len(neighbors)):
    counts.append(len(neighbors[i]))
```

This is significantly faster than the first method and takes 4.697s

3) Now, we can improve the looping time to calculate `counts`.

```
neighbors = tree.query_radius(array, 1)
len_array = np.frompyfunc(len, 1, 1)
counts = len_array(neighbors)
```

This is the **fastest** with 4.449s.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you think you need to do this twice:

```
a = np.random.rand(100,3)*10
tree = KDTree(a)
neighbors = tree.query_radius(a, 1)

%timeit counts = tree.query_radius(a, 1, count_only = 1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 231 µs per loop

%timeit counts = np.array([arr.size for arr in neighbors])
The slowest run took 5.66 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 22.5 µs per loop
```

It's significantly faster to just find the size of the array objects in `neighbors` than to redo `tree.query_radius`